# Условие подстановки переменной lua

Tags: lua

У меня очень маленький опыт работы с lua. У меня есть lua скрипт, который подставляет переменную в Rest API запрос:

```
USR_ID = nil
KROPISANIE = nil
OPISANIE = nil
ITEMID = nil
CATID = nil
TYPETS = nil
OPRICH = nil
SPOSOB = nil
PRICHTS = nil
MERY = nil
VINOV = nil
PRIOR = nil
success, err = ASSYST:connect()
result, err = ASSYST:sql(string.format([[
with assyst_test_bc (USR_ID,KROPISANIE,OPISANIE,ITEMID,CATID,TYPETS,OPRICH,SPOSOB,PRICHTS,MERY,VINOV,PRIOR) AS (
SELECT   i.aff_usr_id AS 'USR_ID',
REPLACE(i.short_desc, ' ', '+') AS 'KROPISANIE',
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(id.remarks, -3, CHARINDEX('<==#', id.remarks)), ' ', '+') as 'OPISANIE',
i.item_id as 'ITEMID',
i.inc_cat_id as 'CATID',
MAX(CASE WHEN cp.jptsys_web_cust_prop_id = 3945 THEN ikd.jptsys_web_lkup_data_sc END) AS 'TYPETS', 
MAX(CASE WHEN cp.jptsys_web_cust_prop_id = 3946 THEN ikd.jptsys_web_lkup_data_sc END) AS 'OPRICH', 
REPLACE(MAX(CASE WHEN cp.jptsys_web_cust_prop_id = 4048 THEN pc.string_value END), ' ', '+') AS 'SPOSOB', 
REPLACE(MAX(CASE WHEN cp.jptsys_web_cust_prop_id = 4051 THEN pc.string_value END), ' ', '+') AS 'PRICHTS', 
REPLACE(MAX(CASE WHEN cp.jptsys_web_cust_prop_id = 4052 THEN pc.string_value END), ' ', '+') AS 'MERY', 
MAX(CASE WHEN cp.jptsys_web_cust_prop_id = 4053 THEN CONVERT(varchar, pc.LOOKUP_VAL_Id) END) AS 'VINOV'
,MAX(CASE WHEN cp.jptsys_web_cust_prop_id = 3925 THEN ikd.jptsys_web_lkup_data_sc END) as 'PRIOR'

FROM         jptsys_web_cust_prop_cont as pc INNER JOIN
                      jptsys_web_cust_prop as cp ON pc.jptsys_web_cust_prop_id = cp.jptsys_web_cust_prop_id INNER JOIN
                      jptsys_web_lkup_data as ikd ON pc.single_sel_val_id = ikd.jptsys_web_lkup_data_id INNER JOIN
                      incident as i ON pc.entity_id = i.incident_id INNER JOIN
                      inc_data as id ON i.incident_id = id.incident_id
 WHERE  i.incident_id = ']] .. EVENT_ID .. [['
 and ikd.jptsys_web_lkup_data_sc not in ('NTC','3TC')
group by i.aff_usr_id,i.short_desc,id.remarks,i.item_id,i.inc_cat_id,i.incident_id 
 )

select *
from assyst_test_bc
where PRIOR IS NOT NULL ]]))
if not result then
    USR_ID = " "
    KROPISANIE = " "
    OPISANIE = " "
    ITEMID = " "
    CATID = " "
    TYPETS = " "
    OPRICH = " "
    SPOSOB = "тест"
    PRICHTS = " "
    MERY = " "
    VINOV = " "
    PRIOR = " "
elseif result.n == 1 then
    USR_ID = result.USR_ID
    KROPISANIE = result.KROPISANIE
    OPISANIE = result.OPISANIE
    ITEMID = result.ITEMID
    CATID = result.CATID
    TYPETS = result.TYPETS
    OPRICH = result.OPRICH
    SPOSOB = result.SPOSOB
    PRICHTS = result.PRICHTS
    MERY = result.MERY
    VINOV = result.VINOV
    PRIOR = result.PRIOR
else 
    USR_ID = " "
    KROPISANIE = " "
    OPISANIE = " "
    ITEMID = " "
    CATID = " "
    TYPETS = " "
    OPRICH = " "
    SPOSOB = "тест"
    PRICHTS = " "
    MERY = " "
    VINOV = " "
    PRIOR = " "
end
ASSYST:disconnect()

local http = require("socket.http")
local http_url = require("socket.url")
local RESULT_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8989/assyst/assystEJB/Event/new?eventType=problem&entityDefinitionId=339&affectedUserId=' .. USR_ID .. "&itemAId=" .. ITEMID .. "&categoryId=" .. CATID .. "&assignedServDeptId=1704&remarks=%22" .. OPISANIE .. "%22&shortDescription=%22" .. KROPISANIE .. "%22&custom.field.4075=%22" .. SPOSOB .. "%22&custom.field.4073=%22" .. TYPETS .. "%22&custom.field.4074=%22" .. OPRICH .. "%22&custom.field.4077=%22" .. PRICHTS .. "%22&custom.field.4078=%22" .. MERY .. "%22&custom.field.4081=" .. VINOV .. "&fields=formattedReference,dateLogged"

local RESULT_REQUEST = http.request(RESULT_URL)
```

Rest API не воспринимает пустое значение, который возвращает sql запрос. Я пытаюсь задать условие в lua, что если sql запрос ничего не возвращает, то в переменную подставлялся текст. В приложенном варианте lua работает, но в rest api запрос не подставляется текст из переменной и поэтому рест не отрабатывает. 
Что я не так делаю?

P.S. дополнительный вопрос: есть ли в lua возможность логировать результат url запроса?

Comment: На будущее:  Старайтесь задавать _один_ вопрос за раз и приводить _минимальный_ код, на котором чётко воспроизводится проблема.  См. также: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: прежде чем коннектиться, `ASSYST` надо создать..

Comment: а лог писать проще всего.. или `print()` в самом скрипте или можно в текстовый файл писать пошагово свои результаты

Answer (score 0):

Вот так?

```
USR_ID = result.USR_ID or ""
    KROPISANIE = result.KROPISANIE or ""
    OPISANIE = result.OPISANIE or ""
    ITEMID = result.ITEMID or ""
    CATID = result.CATID or ""
    TYPETS = result.TYPETS or ""
    OPRICH = result.OPRICH or ""
    SPOSOB = result.SPOSOB or ""
    PRICHTS = result.PRICHTS or ""
    MERY = result.MERY or ""
    VINOV = result.VINOV or ""
    PRIOR = result.PRIOR or ""
```

Если слева от or пустота (nil), то подставится то что справа, то есть "", а если нет, то что слева